# Android Studio does not recognize Mockito

Tags: android

Here is my test class:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class OrmLiteTest {

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        OrmLiteDatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new OrmLiteDatabaseHelper(mMockContext);
    }

}
```

Everything Mockito-related is colored in red and when alt+entering it, there is no "import class" option.

My test class is located in the

```
com.example.myapp
com.example.myapp(androidTest) folder
```

This is part of my `gradle.build` file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
}
```

Comment: If you are using Mockito and JUnit in instrumentation tests, you should change `testCompile` to `androidTestCompile`.

Comment: I want pure unit tests, I already have some instrumentation tests set up

Comment: Then, you have to put your test classes in `src/test/java` dir, and enable `Unit Tests` test artifact in Android Studio.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. test folder is for unit tests, androidTest is for automation tests! It worked right away! Thank you. I would accept this as an answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want pure unit tests, instead of instrumentation Android tests, you have to create your test classes under `src/test/java` directory and change test artifact to 'Unit Tests' in Android Studio (in Build Variants tool window).